# Remove / Update security identities ACL Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, acl

I have read the Symfony2 Security/ACL API but I can not find the way to update/delete and acl_security_identities.

I use this code to remove the aces of user. When I delete all the aces from a user to object I would like also delete the record in table acl_security_identities

```
$idObjeto = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($promotora);

$acl = $this->get('security.acl.provider')->findAcl($idObjeto);

# All aces of my object
$aces = $acl->getObjectAces();

# user to revoke access
$idUsuario = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($usuario);

foreach($aces as $i => $ace) {
    if($idUsuario->equals($ace->getSecurityIdentity())) {

        $acl->deleteObjectAce($i);
    }
}

$this->get('security.acl.provider')->updateAcl($acl);
```

Is that posible? I can not find examples or documentation in the API to access that table.

Also i have this problem https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5787 because i use a mail as username.. Is there any alternative to ACL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented in your GitHub issue and made a PR providing a start about the deletion of a user.

I encourage you to check my post and do something similar for the modification of its username. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/mGTXlTWiMs8/discussion