# Update a security identity (ACL) in Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, acl

I'm using FOSUserBundle to handle my app users. Users can update their usernames or either get deleted by an administrator. Everything is fined on that part, my problem is related to Symfony ACL.

Each user has its own security entity when it's created. For example, if I create an account with *shigeno* username, it results in something like this in database (*acl_security_identities* table):

```
id   | identifier                    | username
...  | ...                           | ...
23   | my\Bundle\Entity\User-shigeno | 1
```

*(ACL identity uses the username! Ouch... Why not the id?)*

Now, I, *shigeno*, change my username to *honda*. *Acl_security_identities* table stays as it is, so all my permission are removed (or, more precisely, they didn't moved with me).

Sure, I can add new ACLs. But:

1. It's painful. I have to get all previous ACL to duplicate, not to mention that I don't have easy access to all security objects when I update or remove a user.
2. It's a big security hole, because if nothing removes the previous ACLs and a new guest chose the username *shigeno*... BAM, it's christmass.

How can I update (and remove if I delete a user) ACL security identity?

Note: I've seen [this similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904285/remove-update-security-identities-acl-symfony2). It didn't answer the update question, moreover, doing a raw SQL request in this context is highly insecure (and yeah, it's ugly too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this Link:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8d39213f4cca19466f84a5656a199eee98602ab1

You have to write a Listner, that updates the acl on preUpdate event. This was described the the commit above.

Greetzzz :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. A shame it's not documented.

Comment: It's in the docs now: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html